# I'm printing a lot of items in a for loop, but the for loop isn't fast enough

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I'm trying to print a lot of strings from a list in a `for` loop. It works fine, but it's too slow. Is there any way to make it faster?

```
import time
import os

board = {
        1:[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        2:[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        3:[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        4:[' ','@',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        5:['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'],
}
while True:
        os.system('clear')
        v = 1
        while v < 6:
                for i in board[v]:
                        print(i, end = ' ')
                v += 1
                print('')
```

In the end it works fine, but it prints too slowly. (It makes the text flash.) Is there a way to speed it up so it looks consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole story on refreshing the screen in games. The idea is not to clear the screen between frames.

```
import time
import os
import atexit

def clear():
  print ("{}[2J{}[;H".format(chr(27), chr(27)), end="")
  return

def move_to(row,col):
  print("{}[{};{}H".format(chr(27), row, col), end="")
  return

def hide_cursor():
  print('{}[?25l'.format(chr(27)), end="")
  return

def show_cursor():
  print('{}[?25h'.format(chr(27)), end="")
  return

atexit.register(show_cursor)

board = {
        1:[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        2:[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        3:[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        4:[' ','@',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
        5:['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'],
}
clear()
hide_cursor()
while True:
        move_to(0,0)
        v = 1
        while v < 6:
                for i in board[v]:
                        print(i, end = ' ')
                v += 1
                print('')
show_cursor()
```

then you can refresh only parts of the screen which have changed.

This only works where terminal supports [ANSI Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) but that's seems ok since you already use "clear".

Answer (score 1):

The text flashing happens also with `C++` while using a small matrix like yours (I have the same problem [`here`](https://github.com/FLAK-ZOSO/Labirint)).

---

I don't think this will optimize your code so much, but I would suggest you to use a `list` over a `dict` in this scope:

```
board = [0,
    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
    [' ','@',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
    ['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#']
]
```

This will do the same thing, a `dict` is useless in this case since you are using `int`s as keys.

Comment: I actually need the dictionary in this situation because I need to move the '@' around the y axis, I'm sure there's a way to do the list but the dictionary makes it easy

Comment: You access a list with [], exactly as you do with your dictionary, for example board[1] is the first line with the list too.

Answer (score 0):

did you try comprehension?

```
board = {
    1: [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    2: [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    3: [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    4: [' ', '@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    5: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
}
[[print(i, end=' ') for i in board[v + 1]] for v in range(len(board))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the board state really is managed this way, you can print line by line rather than char by char:

```py
for row in board:
    print(''.join(row))
```

Or calculate the whole block and issue a single print command immediately after the clear, and only if it actually changed.

```py
def format_board(board):
    return '\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in board)

while True:
    if format_board(board) != board_lastchange_string:
        os.system('clear')
        print(format_board(board))

# if you update the board somewhere, save
# `format_board(board)` to `board_lastchange_string`
```